# Need help in sorting on specific key of dictionary in python 3 on price attribute

Tags: sorting, dictionary, python-3.6

Hi I am trying to sort a list of dictionary. My  goal to to sort dictionary on price basis. I am using python 3.6 .
my initial dictionary is

```
basketContent = {'id': '1940', 'price': 10.8}, {'id': '1234', 'price': 130.5}
```

and i have to sort it. It must populate final dictionary as `{'id': '1234', 'price': 130.5}, {'id': '1940', 'price': 10.8}`

I was using following function

```
def usort(_a, _b):
    if _a['price'] > _b['price']:
        return -1
    elif _b['price'] > _a['price']:
        return 1
    return 0
sorted(basketContent, usort)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass a lambda that takes a dictionary and returns the price value to the key function in sorted. The key function takes only 1 argument and should return some parameter of that argument based on which it sorts the sequence.

Comment: can you get me syntax for lambda price.

i have taken reference from https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2007/09/how-to-sort-python-dictionary-by-keys/

Comment: sorted(d, key=lambda x : d[x]). when just the name of a dictionary is passed to any iterator it loops over the keys of the dictionary. So x is always the key thats passed to the lambda.

Comment: thank for your response. but not working.
i have used  this
sorted(basketContent,  key=lambda price : basketContent[price])
but getting below error
list indices must be integers or slices, not dict

Comment: In my example d was the dict not a list of dicts. X represenrs the keys in the dictiobary d. In your case it'll be sorted(basketcontent, key=lambda item : item[price].

Answer (score 0):

Found this searching something else ...
Well your basketContent is a tuple there .. it is Not sortable.
In Fact your basketContent must be a List of dictionaries.
Then :

```
import operator
basketContent = [ {'id': '1940', 'price': 10.8}, {'id': '1234', 'price': 130.5} ]
basketContent.sort(key=operator.itemgetter('price'), reverse =True)
```